# Apple Mach-O Linker Error after migrating Wikitude Plugin 3.3

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm having several errors after I migrate Wikitude Plugin 3.3 on my Cordova Project. These are my errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
      +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK-3.5.2-Release.a(FBCrypto.o)
      -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK-3.5.2-Release.a(FBCrypto.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability connectionRequired] in CDVReachability.o
      -[CDVReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
      +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK-3.5.2-Release.a(FBCrypto.o)
      -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK-3.5.2-Release.a(FBCrypto.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
   "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability stopNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure why this happen? I've tried changing the "Other linker flags". I tried several other solutions. Please help. :/ Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your link binary with libraries in build phases is like below.

[image]